# How to remove added views programmatically

Tags: java, android, view, dialog

I have a dialog wherein a user can add EditText and also remove it. I have successfully added EditText programmatically but my code for removing it doesn't work. I'm following [this](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/dynamically-add-and-remove-views-in-android) tutorial but in my case setup is inside a dialog.

and also i want to get all the the texts on those EditTexts and store it inside an Array.

This is my code:

```
 public void showSurveyDialog(Context context) {
        ImageButton btnAddChoices, btnRemoveChoice;
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.survey_content);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        btnAddChoices = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_choices);
        LinearLayout choiceLayout = dialog.findViewById(R.id.choice_layout);


        btnAddChoices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View rowView = dialog.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.choice_item, null);
                // Add the new row before the add field button.
                choiceLayout.addView(rowView, choiceLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
                ImageButton imageButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_choice_close);
                imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.e("asdass","ASDASd");
                        choiceLayout.removeView((View)v.getParent());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
```

When pressing btnAddChoices a layout with EditText and Button(for removing) is automatically added to a linear layout. I'am trying to make the remove button to work but it doesn't remove the view.

Comment: what does `choiceLayout.indexOfChild((View)v.getParent())` return?

Comment: it returns the view.. but i don't know which view it returns. please help :(

Comment: the view returns `android.widget.LinearLayout{a0e1ea4 V.E...... ........ 0,0-918,131}`

Comment: no `ViewGroup#indexOfChild()` method does NOT return a `View` it returns `int`, so what is that value?

Comment: i see.. so should I get first the view of that layout? then  the return view will be the one to put inside the `removeView` ?

Comment: basically you cannot remove a view that is not a **direct** child - thats why i asked for `indexOfChild` return value: if it is < 0 it means that this view is not a direct child

Comment: Sir I got the value.. it's `-1` :(

Comment: this is what i told you: you have to get the parent of the view you want to remove and call `parent.removeView(child)`

Comment: How can I do it based on my code above? The parent layout is `choiceLayout` and the child layout is `choice_item`

Comment: which view do you want to remove actually?

Comment: the `choice_item` layout sir.. I have set the view of my dialog to `survey_content` then inside it, there is a LinearLayout which is the `choice_layout` it is a layout with empty child in my xml.. then populating the `choice_layout` with `choice_item` layout which is currently working. By the way, inside of my `choice_item` there is an EditText and a Delete button ( to remove the choices)

Comment: so get the parent of `choice_item` and call `parent.removeView(choice_item)`

Comment: I'm stuck in here
```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choice_item, null);
                ViewParent parent = rowView.getParent();
```
parent doesn't have `removeView`

Comment: `ViewGroup#removeView`

Comment: I don't know how to get the parent of `choice_item` using my code above :(

Comment: use `View#getParent()`

Comment: it's not working

Comment: not workink? it returns `null` or what?

Comment: I logged the `rowView` and returns null

Comment: it is not working sir.

Comment: 14 examples here: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.view.ViewGroup&method=getParent

Answer (score 0):

you can try my add and remove code for references, this can add or remove view programmatically:

```
private void addressField(View view){
        final int[] textCount = {0};
        LinearLayout addressLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.address_layout);
        addressScroll.removeView(addressLayout);
        View layout2 = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.address_text_field
                , addressLayout,false);
        layout2.setTag("address"+Integer.toString(counter));
        addressLayout.addView(layout2);
        addressScroll.addView(addressLayout);
        ImageView deleteButton = layout2.findViewWithTag("address"+Integer.toString(counter))
                .findViewById(R.id.delete_address);
        TextFieldBoxes addressText = layout2.findViewWithTag("address"+Integer.toString(counter))
                .findViewById(R.id.address_wrapper);
        addressText.setSimpleTextChangeWatcher((theNewText, isError) -> {
            if(Objects.equals(theNewText, "")){
                textCount[0] = 0;
                addressLayout.removeView(layout2);
            }

            if(theNewText.length() == 1 && textCount[0] == 0){
                addressField(view);
                ExtendedEditText addressText2 = layout2.findViewWithTag("address"+Integer.toString(counter-1))
                        .findViewById(R.id.address_text);
                addressText2.requestFocus();
                counter++;
            }

            textCount[0]++;
        });
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addressLayout.removeView(layout2);
            }
        });
    }
```

hope can solve your problems